# setting an environment variable in Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, jenkins, tfs

I am trying to run this command on the picture within the Jenkins builder
However, i get
"tf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
tf are commands which work within Visual Studio or through the Visual Studio Command prompt tfpt.exe which is why I was trying to set an environment variable..Oh and I can't use the EnvInject Plugin cuz we just don't use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The command should be:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;%PATH%
```

You are missing `=` after SET PATH, further, your newly added path should point to the **folder containing TF.exe** and not to TF.exe itself.

Answer (score 0):

This command need a **VS or Team Explorer installed**. Make sure your Jenkins

build agent have one of them installed.

Besides you are lacking of "=" with `set path =`